# Like button not passing URL parameters

Tags: button, parameters, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

I'm making a site which has a list of videos. Next to each video in the list I want a like button. My like button code looks like this:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="100" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

And the URL of the page is

```
http://dev2-rs-www.doubledip.com/video-play/?vid=aj5pbnNlcnRlZC1mcm9tLXRleHQtaW4tYnVpbGQtZGVwbG95LWFwcGxpY2F0aW9uaWQtb24tZGVwbG95bWVudHIkCxINQWNjb3VudFJlY29yZBgBDAsSC1ZpZGVvUmVjb3JkGAkM
```

However, the link on my wall is http://dev2-rs-www.doubledip.com/video-play/ without the ?vid= parameter. I also tried adding the data-href attribute, but that didn't do anything. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies with the misuse of the `<link rel='canonical'>` element. On the video page, it links to the page without the ?vid parameter, causing it to use that as the final value. Change it to the actual page and it should work fine.

Comment: You were right. I didn't have the full link in my canonical link tag. That that seemed to fix the problem.

Comment: @echeese, pls see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16059918/facebook-like-button-ignore-url-parameters/16060616?noredirect=1#16060616

Answer (score 0):

Facebook like buttons doesnt use parameters in url.
User this: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/
to check for info and errors

Comment: Thanks, that was a useful tool.